# How to display only last data point on highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a multiple line chart that will be dynamically updated every day (or more). I know the start and end dates (it will last 2 months).

I want to display only the point of the last data entry but not the older ones. Basically, I want my series to look like this : http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/JVNjs/281/

`data: [7,12,16,32,{y:64,marker:{enabled:true,radius:5,fillColor:'#c00'}}]`

or more accurately, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpQF1.jpg

Problem is that my chart updates several time during the day. So I want to display the last updated data on the right day AND to display only the last point. I've tried to select the series' last data by using "lenght - 1" but it didn't work since I'm no expert on JS.

Is there a way to do that ?
Thanks and ask for better explanations if needed. I'm not sur I was quite clear.

Comment: So each day, you add new point which should have a marker, but from "previous day" marker should disappear, am I right ?

Comment: Exact, you're right.

Comment: See the simple demo http://jsfiddle.net/rjpjwve0/ and let me know if that is correct.

Comment: That's exactly what I want ! Thanks a lot Sebastian, it solved my problem.

Comment: I added this example as answer, so you can accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add marker to last point, then in setInterval, remove from that and add to new point.

```
load: function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0],
                    len = series.data.length;

                //set marker on last point
                series.data[len - 1].update({
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                });


                setInterval(function () {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Math.random();

                    len = series.data.length;

                    series.data[len - 1].update({
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }, false);

                    series.addPoint({
                        x: x,
                        y: y,
                        marker: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }, true, true);
                }, 1000);
            }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rjpjwve0/